# Exclude menu item from collapsing Bootsrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have seen several questions related to this, but none seemed to solve my problem. I want to exclude some menu items from collapsing when on mobile. Specifically the "User Name" item in this example. I have managed to get it working (so-so), but the left margin disappears when on mobile. Any solutions to this?

Here is my code:

```
   <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">

        <div class="navbar-header">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">

            <li> <a href="#"> User Name </a> </li>

            </ul>


            <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

        </div>

        <!-- Collection of nav links and other content for toggling -->
        <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"> <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">Messages</a></li>
                <li class="visible-xs" ><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `navbar-brand` instead which will have the proper alignment on mobile..

http://www.codeply.com/go/CM2sytawRI

```
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <div class="navbar-brand"><a class="" href="#"> User Name </a></div>
        <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Collection of nav links and other content for toggling -->
    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"> <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">Messages</a></li>
            <li class="visible-xs"><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Would using the navbar-brand class not cause any confusion for screen readers? Or css classes have nothing to do with that? Also, is bootstrap okay with having more than one navbar-brands? Thanks!